# Split XML file with XSLT 2.0 based on element count

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Huge XML with the following structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<productall>

<product type="electronics" date="1-1-2016">

<type name"Androidbased">

      <product> InStock </product>

</type>      

</product>

<product type="cloths" date="1-12-2008">

<type name"Jeans">

      <product> InStock </product>

</type>      

</product>

<product type="bags" date="1-12-2008">

<type name"FF">

      <product> InStock </product>

</type>      

</product>


</productall>
```

each product type has thousands of records for example electronics are 2000 records and cloths are 8000 records.

I want to split this XML file into multiple XMLs with 1000 records each regardless the type!

I have used XSLT 2.0 based on java & saxon 9 to split it but it doesn't work as it should here is what I did so far :

`java -jar sax.jar productall.xml split.xslt`

Split.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="productall" select="1000"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/productall/product[@type]">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="product" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv $productall">
            <xsl:result-document href="part.{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
                <productall>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"></xsl:copy-of>
                </productall>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is printed out on the terminal screen without XML format and no .XML files are generated. Don't know what is wrong the command syntax or the contents of the XSLT file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is your template matches a `product` element, which means when you do the `xsl:for-each-group`, you will be positioned on the `product` element. Then you are selecting `product` elements, ye the these are not children of the current element, but of the `type` elements. So, you need to do this...

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="type/product" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv $productall">
```

However, you say you want multiple XMLs with 1000 records each regardless the type, but the current XSLT does this for each main product separately, meaning you will get duplicate file names.

Perhaps you should include the main product type in the file name?

```
<result-document href="part.{../../@type}.{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
```

Or if you really did want to do it regardless of main product type, you should change your main template to match `productall` instead.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="productall" select="1000"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/productall">
         <xsl:for-each-group select="product/type/product" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv $productall">
            <xsl:result-document href="part.{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
                <productall>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"></xsl:copy-of>
                </productall>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to change `match="/productall/product[@type]"` to `match="/productall"`.